# Angular - Hide items if > 5 on ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a filter list which have 50 items. I just want to show 5 items and hide the rest to make a "Show More" button.

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="a in filters.area">
         <input type="checkbox" ng-change="filter()" ng-model="a.checked"> {{ a.name }}
    </li>
</ul>
<span>SHOW MORE</span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`LimitTo`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo) in Angular

```
 <li ng-repeat="n in numbers | limitTo:numLimit">{{n}}</li>
```

Here is a sample [`JsFiddle`](http://fiddle.jshell.net/sajeetharan/bxbw2756/)

Answer (score 2):

Use `limitTo` filter in AngularJS

`{{ limitTo_expression | limitTo : limit : begin}}`

[Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo)

Something like this for your example:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="a in filters.area | limitTo: 5">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-change="filter()" ng-model="a.checked">
        {{a.name}}
    </li>
</ul>
<span>SHOW MORE</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27437882/angular-directive-with-ng-repeat-ng-show-show-more-and-lazy-load) and this demo [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PuttD9Cp2dM2EsSvyY8z?p=preview)

```
<foo ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo: limit as results" n="{{item}}"></foo>
<button ng-hide="results.length === items.length" ng-click="limit = limit +2">show more...</button>
```