# Show more button in ngFor in angular2

Tags: angular, button, typescript, show-hide, ngfor

I have a list of over 50 items. I would like to show only the first 10 items, and I would have a button that when clicked shows the next 10 items, and which clicked again, the next 10 items until all is shown.

```html
<ul class="results-main-content">
  <li class="right-results-section">
    <ul class="_result-list">
      <li class="result" *ngFor="let searchResult of searchResults">
        {{searchResult.name}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="showmore">
    <button class="show-more">
      <img class="more" src="_arrow-down.svg" alt="" />
    </button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Is this possible to achieve in angular2?

If so, please enlighten me and the SO community.

Thanks

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42458664/how-to-show-1-element-in-ngfor-in-angular2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the below code

```
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <ul class="results-main-content">
  <li class="right-results-section">
    <ul class="_result-list">
      <li class="result" *ngFor="let item of content">
        {{item.colorName}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="showmore">
    <button class="show-more" (click)="getData()" [disabled]="counter>=content.length">
      Show more
    </button>
  </li>
</ul>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  data = [...]; // refer plunker
  content:any[]=new Array();
  counter:number;
  constructor() {
    this.counter=0;
    this.getData();
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }
  getData(){
    console.log(this.counter + 'dat size'+this.data.length)

    for(let i=this.counter+1;i<this.data.length;i++)
    {
    this.content.push(this.data[i]);
    if(i%10==0) break;
    }
    this.counter+=10;

  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/rkTlnnClu7tjHC19UC41?p=preview)**

Comment: How would I ensure that it only shows 10 items on click?

Comment: see the if condition inside the for loop

Comment: I believe its not the condition in for loop. Its the condition that we assign in the `[diabled]` handler.

Comment: Because when you click the button, its says that view al of it. But thats not what i want. What i want is to only show 10 items for every click that the suer does

Comment: So basically, by default the first 10 item should be shown. And when you click on the button, the next 10 item is shown. When click again, the next 10 item is shown.

Comment: So basically, for each click, you show the next 10 items until there is no more left

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137715/discussion-between-aravind-and-dingdong).

Answer (score 14):

You can use the slice pipe:

```
show = 5;
```

```
<li *ngFor="let searchResult of searchResults|slice:0:show let i=index">
  {{searchResult.name}}
  <button *ngIf="i==4 && show == 5" (click)="show = searchResults.length">More</button>
</li>
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/ViTn7chwIVUoeHt6IIOK?p=preview)

See also

- [How to show 1 element in ngFor in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42458664/how-to-show-1-element-in-ngfor-in-angular2)

Answer (score 6):

By modifying Günter Zöchbauer code, you can achieve this by looking at this example

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
<ul>  
 <li *ngFor="let tag of tags | slice:0:show; let i=index">
  <a href="#" class="span-tag tag">{{ tag }}</a>
 </li>
<div *ngIf="show < tags.length" (click)="increaseShow()">DropDown Button</div>
</ul>
`,
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  show = 10;
  tags = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j', 'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j', 'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j'];

  increaseShow() {
   this.show += 10; 
 }
}
```

[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hhxawo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)