# Tailwind grid layout

Tags: css, angular, css-grid, tailwind-css

I am trying to display a grid layout of 2 rows with 6 columns using Tailwind within my Angular project.

The actors array I am looping over consists of 25 actors. So the goal here is to display 12 actors over 2 rows and then display a "show more" button to display the remaining actors.

Currently I get 6 columns but the rows seem to be ignored as I get 5 rows currently and not 2.

What am I missing here?

**HTML**

```
<div class="grid grid-rows-2 grid-cols-6 mt-4 gap-4">
  <div *ngFor="let actor of actors" class="flex flex-col gap-2">
    <div class="w-full aspect-h-1 aspect-w-1 rounded overflow-hidden">
      <img src="{{actor.imageUrl}}" alt="Picture of actor">
    </div>
    <span class="text-white text-center">{{actor.name}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: CSS Grid cannot hide anything on your behalf just because it's outside the declared row amount. The content outside your template-rows rule will simply take on the default grid placement. You will need to take care of the data that is passed to the HTML yourself, here's a question where they solved it with a slice pipe in Angular https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42708092/show-more-button-in-ngfor-in-angular2

Comment: Thanks for clearing that!

Answer (score 1):

It's seems this doesn't work like that, so the easiest way is to slice "actors" array to 12 index like below code, and show remaining actors to show more button.

```
<div *ngFor='let item of items | slice:start:end'>
```