# How to split *ngFor in 4 parts each? in angular

Tags: angular, angular6

How can I split this code output in 4 each part?
Is it somehow possible to use ngFor and tell it to divide the array into batches and display it dynamically?

```
<h4>Reservation Slots</h4>

<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr  *ngFor="let slots of reservationSlotsList" >
        <td class="text-center">{{slots}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to be expected output

```
  <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center">my-slot1</td>
            <td class="text-center">my-slot2</td>
            <td class="text-center">my-slot3</td>
            <td class="text-center">my-slot4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center">my-slot1</td>
            <td class="text-center">my-slot2</td>
            <td class="text-center">my-slot3</td>
            <td class="text-center">my-slot4</td>
        </tr>
        ...

    </table>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show 1 element in ngFor in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42458664/how-to-show-1-element-in-ngfor-in-angular2)

Answer (score 0):

it can be:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr  *ngFor="let tr of trs;let j=index" >
        <td class="text-center" *ngFor="let slots of reservationSlotsList;let i=index" class="text-center">{{slots}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

ts example:

```
reservationSlotsList = ['my-slot1' , 'my-slot2','my-slot3', 'my-slot4' ]
trs = [0 , 1]
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fgzk8r)

Comment: Sorry for the not sharing the `reservationSlotsList` array. Actually it is
`reservationSlotsList = ['my-slot1' , 'my-slot2','my-slot3', 'my-slot4', 'my-slot5' , 'my-slot6','my-slot7', 'my-slot8', . . .]`
and the result must be
```<tr>
            <td class="text-center">my-slot1</td>
            <td class="text-center">my-slot2</td>
            <td class="text-center">my-slot3</td>
            <td class="text-center">my-slot4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center">my-slot4</td>
            <td class="text-center">my-slot5</td>
            ...
</tr>```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best for you is to create a custom function like this one inside your component :

```
nArray(n: number): any[] {
    return Array(n);
}
```

And inside your html:

```
<h4>Reservation Slots</h4>
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr  *ngFor="let item of nArray(4)" > // 4 for your particular use
        <td class="text-center" *ngFor="let slots of reservationSlotsList">{{slots}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```